# What does this `iptables -t filter -X` command mean

Tags: 16.04, server, iptables, firewall

What does this command mean:

```
iptables -t filter -X
```

What is the purpose of `-X`?
And what's the difference between `-X` and `-F`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is answered by the manpage (see `man iptables` on the command line):

```
-F, --flush [chain]
    Flush the selected chain (all the chains in the table if none is given). 
    This is equivalent to deleting all the rules one by one.

-X, --delete-chain [chain]
    Delete the optional user-defined chain specified. There must be no references
    to the chain. If there are, you must delete or replace the referring rules 
    before the chain can be deleted. The chain must be empty, i.e. not contain any 
    rules If no argument is given, it will attempt to delete every non-builtin 
    chain in the table.
```

And though you didn't ask, the small bit on `-t` here (I remvoed a large portion of the data here, because it can all be read in `man iptables`):

```
-t, --table table
    This option specifies the packet matching table which the command should 
    operate on. If the kernel is configured with automatic module loading, 
    an attempt will be made to load the appropriate module for that table if it 
    is not already there.
```